# Swift 3 UITableViewCell Alamofire Image Update

Tags: swift, xcode

how would I update my imageView inside UITableViewCell from URL via Alamofire on a regular interval (e.g. every 1 second)?

Comment: Is image at the your url is changing regularly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do it with a timer?

E.G:

```
var changeImageTimer= Timer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("changeImage"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func changeImage() 
{
    //Code to change your image here
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't specify which version of swift. Code can be converted up in Xcode